# is it possible to set jQuery UI's datepciker onselect callback after it's you have called $('#myid').datepicker()

Tags: jquery-ui

I am a contractor and don't really have the power to mess with certain things and unfortunately there is a page that calls an html helper they built that spews out an input with the class of "date" whenever there is DateTime passed to it, then in the main template they have this

```
function hijaxInputs(elementId) {
    $('#' + elementId + ' input.date').datepicker({ changeYear: true, showOn: 'button', buttonImage: '/Content/css/images/Calendar.gif', buttonImageOnly: true });
    $('#' + elementId + ' input[mask]').each(function(i) {
        $(this).mask($(this).attr('mask'));
    });
}
```

which is lame because I can't control the way the input is rendered and then I can't control the application of datepicker to the element. I tried to do it after the fact but that seems to fail. I tried this.

```
$('#consentDocumentsTbl [id$=SubmissionDate]').onSelect = function (dateText, inst) { console.log("Err..."); };
```

But that was a no go - did I just make a simple syntax error or is what I want to do impossible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the `onSelect` function after initialization using the widget's `option` function like this:

```
$('#consentDocumentsTbl [id$=SubmissionDate]').datepicker('option', 'onSelect', 
    function (dateText, inst) { console.log("Err..."); });
```

Comment: Thanks - That totally works. Gabe's answer did not work for me. It was the first thing I tried and I even tried it again. You totally made my day!